# How to make a QR code scanner like in Paytm android app which was included recently?

Tags: java, android, animation, camera, effects

I have already completed making such an app but I require the animation and the effects on the surface view as paytm has provided which is demonstrated in the image.

How can I make a start on the animations and the effects on the camera?

Paytm QR code scanner:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GLSurface view over the Camera Screen (Surfaceview) where you can show any View. To show anything above camera preview Layer. Just Checkout the demo given at Google developer. This is Basic of you can implement Anything. You may find Library for Barcode Scan. But Internally they will be using the same.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html

Comment: Can you please give me a more concrete example?

Comment: There is an Example at developer site. GLSurface view is an Another View above surfaceview (Preview from Camera). Where you can draw object or views. Check out below. Actually I m using it for AR (Augmented Reality) development. 

https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html

Comment: Thanks!! But  by any means if you obtain any sample code similar to my requirement please let me know :)

Comment: Ok sure. If I find I will reply you back.

Comment: Can you provide any example HTML/jsfiddle